# Checking if item is in list says it is true, then wont let me reference the index because it says the item is not in the list

Tags: python, list

I create a list:

```
temp_cards = []
```

then add values to the list:

```
for number in cards:
    for type in suits:
        temp_cards.append(str(number) + " of " + str(type))
```

and then I choose a random value from the list and try to get the index - but it says it isn't in the list.

```
dealers_card = random.choice(temp_cards)
y = cards.index(dealers_card)
print(y)
# ValueError: 'Two of Clubs' is not in list
```

but i checked if it is in the list and it says true

```
x = dealers_card in temp_cards
print(x)
# True
```

Comment: You are looking in two different lists - `temp_cards` and `cards`.

Answer (score 1):

`temp_cards` consists of a series of strings in the format "number of suit". That string is not in `cards`, which consists of a series of numbers.